# Error sending database from xCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, sqlite, email

I am trying to send a sqlite database attached to a mail from my iphone app, I receive the email but not the database file, sorry about my grammar,I am from Spain, here is my code.

```
-(IBAction)mandar:(id)sender
{   
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
    {
        [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Introducir direccion",nil]];
        [composer setSubject:@"Base de datos"];
        [composer setMessageBody:@"Mensage" isHTML:YES];
        [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"capturas.sqlite"];

        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];

        [composer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/sqlite" fileName:@"capturas.sqlite"];

        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No se a podido mandar el mensage" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dismis" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

application/x-sqlite3 instead of application/sqlite for mimeType

EDIT: This solved it and sent the file:

```
-(IBAction)mandar:(id)sender {

MFMailComposeViewController *composer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
{
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"EMAIL Address here",nil]];
    [composer setSubject:@"Base de datos"];
    [composer setMessageBody:@"Mensage" isHTML:YES];
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
```

Commented these from your code:

//NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"capturas.sqlite"];

//NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];

And replaced with the following

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database name without extension" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    [composer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:path];

    [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No se a podido mandar el mensage" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dismis" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

}

Comment: also set isHTML: to NO and if not working you can check this link for reference (http://principalhuman.com/content/sending-email-attachment-using-apple-iphone-sdk-xcode-40)

Comment: on it but still no results, the error has to be in this line  [composer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite" fileName:@"capturas.sqlite"];

Comment: I don't see an issue with the code so I would recommend checking the common mistakes like not adding the file in project tree or checking the file extension,..etc

Comment: checked everything, the database is there and I can add fields, and its a sqlite file etc etc, dont know what to do.

Comment: Check the solution above please