# Attaching sqlite to xcode mail

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite, email

I am going crazy with this code, It should be working but when I receive the mail there is no file attached, here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)mandar:(id)sender
{   
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
    {
        [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tuperroensalsa@hotmail.com",nil]];
        [composer setSubject:@"Base de datos"];
        [composer setMessageBody:@"Mensage" isHTML:NO];
        [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
            NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/capturas.sqlite",documentPath];

        NSString *Newpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/newData.sqlite",documentPath];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:path toPath:Newpath error:nil];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:Newpath];
        [composer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:@"capturas.sqlite"];

        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No se a podido mandar el mensage" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dismis" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

The path is ok and the database has data in it, I also see the file when I am composing the mail but nothing arrives to my mail. I guess the problem is here

```
[composer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:@"capturas.sqlite"];
```

but dont know why it doesnt works, thx for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error sending database from xCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499971/error-sending-database-from-xcode)

Comment: You can attach the sqlite file, but you never could be able to open it for example, via LiYa app on MAC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've updated the answer already at: [Error sending database from xCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499971/error-sending-database-from-xcode) but it seems you didn't check it, anyway here it's again:

```
-(IBAction)mandar:(id)sender {

MFMailComposeViewController *composer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
{
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"EMAIL Address here",nil]];
    [composer setSubject:@"Base de datos"];
    [composer setMessageBody:@"Mensage" isHTML:YES];
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
```

Commented these from your code:

```
//  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//  NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"capturas.sqlite"];
//  NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

And replaced with the following

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database name without extension" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    [composer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:path];

    [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No se a podido mandar el mensage" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dismis" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

}

Comment: interesting... the mime types supported by `- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment  mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType  fileName:(NSString*)filename` are listed here http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml . There is no `application/x-sqlite3` type. Will try the code on a real environment.

Comment: is this able to attach .db file ?

Comment: Yes, it should be able to attach any file as long as you will change the file name, extension and mimeType which should be application/octet-stream in that case and as long as that file is readable by iOS. Please give the feedback after trying this so other users can find the answer if they needed it.

Comment: Got empty data in SQLite

Comment: Can you please post swift version of this solution @XIII

Comment: Can somebody translate this into swift for saving and sending SQLite via email

Comment: @KirtiNikam did you able to send sqlite through mail with data present in it.I also tried but I also got empty data in attachement of sqlite.

Comment: @poojathorat, i was using coredata and able send sqlite file, please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/56151110/1635315

Comment: @KirtiNikam,I attached wal file as well now in mail attachment but still Sqlite file is empty.Can you post your code ?